# Create Pyspark Dataframe from Key Value Pair log file with variable contents

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a log file in key=value pair format and would like to read the contents into an rdd, process the rdd into a data frame, and perform aggregations/analysis with spark SQL. I can read the raw data to rdd but I haven't been able to find an example of how to process key value pairs into a tabular format.

To complicate matters, the log can and does have missing key value pairs, so the format is variable. I would hope to be able to get around this by having NULL values in rows where that 'column'/key=value is missing once processed to data frame.

Below is an example of the log :

```
"Date"="2017-07-11T15:55:07-07:00","recordType"="ap_data","apName"="ap1","numClients"="5","version"="2.1"
"Date"="2017-07-11T15:55:07-07:00","recordType"="ap_data","apName"="ap2","numClients"="4","version"="2.1"
"Date"="2017-07-11T15:55:07-07:00","recordType"="ap_data","apName"="ap3","version"="2.1"
```

Notice the third event is missing the "numClients" key-value pair.

All I've managed to do so far is read the raw content to RDD:

```
#Initializing PySpark
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.types import Row

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate()

# Read raw contents to a new RDD and print first 2 results
raw_data = sc.textFile("log_sample.log")
raw_data.take(2)
```

Kindly please provide some help with reading key-value pair formatted data and processing to tabular format. Else, if this is not the right approach, I'm open to suggestion(s). Thank you!

Below is the data frame structure I hope to produce:

EDIT: Apologies, for clarity I'm not trying to produce any HTML, just wanted to show an example of tabular result, not sure why the html is showing and not just rendering the table.

```html
<style type="text/css">
.tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
.tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;padding:10px 5px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
.tg .tg-yw4l{vertical-align:top}
</style>
<table class="tg">
  <tr>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">Date</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">recordType</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">apName</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">numClients</th>
    <th class="tg-yw4l">version</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2017-07-11T15:55:07-07:00</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">ap_data</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">ap1</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">5</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2017-07-11T15:55:07-07:00</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">ap_data</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">ap2</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">4</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2.1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2017-07-11T15:55:07-07:00</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">ap_data</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">ap3</td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l"></td>
    <td class="tg-yw4l">2.1</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: ,Sorry to ask , I know its a very old question but have you had any solutions that you were looking for. For spark 3.0 , from_csv would help solve this issue, anything other than that, I am using spark.2.4 at the moment!!